# jQuery FileUpload with Laravel and NOT autoupload

Tags: jquery, laravel, file-upload

I'm having a lot of problems with the jQuery FileUpload with the AutoLoad turned off. I need everything to be submitted in one request--not multiple. I have had 3 days of fighting this and LOTS of research. I just have a feeling I'm missing one thing. Here's what I got:

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

var ul = $('#upload ul');

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
$('#entry_form_doc').fileupload({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'leadresources/submitDoc',
    limitMultiFileUploads: 5,
    autoUpload: false,
    dropZone: $('#drop'),
    add: function (e, data) {

//fired by a click of a button.
        $("#submit_doc").unbind('click').on('click', function(){
            data.formData = {files: data.originalFiles};
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    fail:function(e, data){
        // Something has gone wrong!
        data.context.addClass('error');
    }

});
```

});

This is what Laravel gets when I print_r() it into the Log:

```
 [2015-03-16 14:27:27] production.INFO: Array
(
    [lb_id] => 
    [lb_doc_title] => asdf
    [lb_docs_summary] => 
    [file] => Array
        (
            [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
                (
                    [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                    [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => photo 2.JPG
                    [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
                    [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 498589
                    [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\php31F9.tmp
                    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php31F9.tmp
                )
        )
)
 [] []
    )
     [] []
```

Right now, it's only returning the first object and nothing else. I guess that makes sense since the data.submit is being fired on the first image and then unbinding.

For a long time, I was getting multiple submits, but I only want it submitted once with a fileListArray--not an individual file. I tried to create a File List Array but Laravel logs a [object FileList] and that's it.

So has anyone else been able to get this to fire without autoLoad and in one request--not multiple. I have followed the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#singlefileuploads) that talks about singleFileUploads but still...didn't work.

Just curious if anyone else is at wits in with this. It's a great plugin--just REALLY hard to figure out.

### **EDIT:**

I should also say that the reason why I wanted autoload to be turned off is that I needed 3 form fields to be submitted to return an ID first so I can attach the ID to those documents.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an answer (so I'm not going to mark it), but I did find another plugin that was waaaaay less temperamental. I ended up just using [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). It was easier to use and had more the functionality that I was looking for.

**EDIT**
I was asked how I did it using Dropzone. Here's how I did it:

```
$("#entryDoc").dropzone({ 
    url: "submitDoc",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFiles: 5,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    autoProcessQueue:false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    thumbnailWidth: 100,
    thumbnailHeight: 100,
    paramName: 'files',
    dictRemoveFile: 'X',
    dictCancelUpload: 'Cancel',
    dictFallbackMessage: 'Your browser does not support dropzone. Please update your browser',
    dictInvalidFileType: 'File type not accepted. It has been removed from the queue.',
    dictFileTooBig: 'File is too big. It has been removed from the queue.',
    maxfilesexceeded: 'Only 5 files can be uploaded.',
    dictResponseError: 'Could not upload your files. Please try again or reach out to the developer.',
    fallback: function(){
        $('#entryDoc').html('Please update your browser.');
    },
    init: function(){
        var myDropZone = this;

        myDropZone.on("sendingmultiple", function (files, xhr, formData) {     //this form data gets sent over with the files.
            formData.append("action", $('#action').val());
            formData.append("lb_type_code", 'files');
            formData.append("lb_id", $('#lb_id').val());
        });

        $("#submit_doc").click(function () {
            var check = formValidation($('#files_container'));

            if(!check){
                $.jqDialog.alert("You are missing some required fields.");
                return false;
            }

            myDropZone.processQueue();
        });
    }, 
    success: function(){
        //what you want it to do after it successfully uploaded
    }, 
    error: function(file, errorMessage){
        //error here
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, did you implement what you wanted with Dropzone?

Comment: Hey @AsmeJust - Yes, I got it working. Dropzone was friendly to work with.

Comment: Well that's cool, it's been a week that am trying to implement exactely what you wanted in this post with no luck... can you send me part of your code if you don't mind please?

Comment: Hey @AsmeJust, it took me about a week of attempting to get it done with the other before I gave up also. I can certainly help you out. I posted my code up above. I hope it helps! I've got quite a few comments in the code.

Comment: Hey @AsmeJust, did that help you any?

Comment: Hey @cbloss793 I am really sorry for late reply... I "gave up" since but... will check your code for ... I will let you know. Thanks.